# Chosen/Select2 jQuery Plugins Aren't Working With IE10

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-plugins, internet-explorer-10

The following code which targest ASP.NET MVC 4 works correctly on Firefox and Chrome (the page loads without error and the dropdown displays/responds correctly), however IE10 throws the following when the page loads:

**> 0x800a01b6 - JavaScript runtime error: Object doesn't support property or method 'chosen'**

This is the SELECT html markup:

```
<select class="chzn-select" data-placeholder="Group" name="Group">
    @foreach(var group in @Model.Groups)
    {
      <option value="@group">@group</option>
    }
</select>
```

And the JavaScript below it:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $(".chzn-select").chosen();
    });
</script>
```

I have added the chosen.css and chosen.*.js files to the appropriate Style and Script bundles, which I then included in my master page.

(screen of dev tools on page request)
[image]

Also, I tried with select2 and it experienced the same error in IE, the other browsers worked fine. (I updated the bundles to include references to the .css and .js) The code I changed was:

```
<select class="GroupDropdown" name="Group">
      @foreach(var group in @Model.Groups)
      {
         <option value="@group">@group</option>
      }
 </select>
 <script type="text/javascript">
      $(function () {
           $(".GroupDropdown").select2();
      });
 </script>
```

The following works on all browsers (with the files in root and named correctly)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Dropdown Test</title>
    <script src="jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="select2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <link href="select2.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
<body>
    <select>
        <option value="A">A</option>
        <option value="B">B</option>
        <option value="C">C</option>
    </select>
</body>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
        $("select").select2();
    });
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: Are you sure the script is actually getting loaded?

Comment: Which script are you referring to? If it is the one in the question, how can I check? (The chosen .js, .css and jQuery are all being downloaded according to IE10 dev tools)

Comment: I meant the chosen .js. But then that's not the problem

Comment: try to change your jquery.js with later version of 1.8.1 and not 1.9.1 something.

Comment: Thank you kindly! I added a reference to jQuery 1.8.3 in place of 1.9.1 and it now works. Do you know the reason behind this?

Comment: Also, you should place your stylesheets above your javascript.

Comment: @HennyH It's weird because with 1.9.1, it works on [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/UH6QU/)

Comment: @Shikiryu yeah, I made a simple html file (the last segment of code in the question) using the jQuery library which the ASP.NET MVC setup was using and it worked! The problem would seem to lie in the MVC framework.

Comment: @HennyH And... that's where I can't help you :/

Comment: @Shikiryu I ended up using token input instead, it has been working perfectly.

Comment: There should be an asnwer to this question, since it is solved, anyone of the commenters wanting to post it as an answer?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem recently, ensure you are using a stable jquery version later than 1.8.1